# Do you say "I got/had/took a vaccine for the flu"?

Tags: grammar

I thought all of them were correct, but I was told "had a vaccine" is the idiomatic usage. Why is that? Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide some context. For example, *who* told you? What part of the world are you in? Are you talking about the physical administration of the vaccine or about the general concept of being vaccinated? In casual conversation I'm not very likely to use any of your examples; here in the US I'd say something like *I received a flu shot* or *I was given a flu shot*.

Comment: Someone from Britain, I presume. What's the active form though? "I got myself a vaccine for the flu (I received it from a nurse today)?"

Comment: I might say *I had my vaccination for the flu*, or more likely *I had my flu vaccination*, but *I had a vaccine for the flu* sounds to me like you are a microbiologist whose research was stymied, or maybe that you were a courier for a vaccine delivery service and handled a shipment of flu vaccine this afternoon. :-) But again, this is from an American who does not work in medicine or epidemiology, and I have no idea if this is the normal way to express it elsewhere in the world. That is why I asked you to provide a locale and other context.

Comment: But why is got or took wrong? I don't understand why it should be considered wrong.

Comment: They're not considered wrong. That's my point. Without additional context, we have no idea why "somebody" would have told you that they were wrong. Some might object to *get* because they hate the word *get*, which imparts some informality. Some may dislike *take* because it implies oral administration, when the flu vaccine is administered nasally or via injection.

Comment: **Took** is used for oral medication, not injected shots. "I thought I had to **get** a vaccine shot, but I found out that I can **take** a pill instead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I had a vaccination

is nonstandard, as well as

> I took a vaccination

I've noticed that generally, the only common English use of this phrase is

> **I was vaccinated**

or **"I got vaccinated".**

The person who told you was mistaken; "had a vaccine" is not idiomatic.